# Storing JSON in an objective C NSString

Tags: objective-c, json

NSString removes the backslashes from the JSON. I'm eventually passing the variable into another javascript function that JSON.parses it. Because the backslashes are removed, the JSON.parse is failing.

```
JSON = "[\"test\"]"
NSString = "[test]" (Stored as)
JSON.parse(NSString) -> fails
```

Comment: Put _two_ backslashes? `"[\\\"test\\\"]"` (just an idea, haven't tried it)

Comment: Post the actual code that isn't working. All that I can see from your question is that you did stuff and it didn't work. Not going to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@[JSON] options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: jsonData];
```

This worked for me.

Comment: okay please dont forget to Accept the answer ,select the checkmark

Comment: `encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` should be on the second line, not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

use it

```
 NSString*  str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@[JSON] options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```